# Ajax post method not fire MVC controller method in View without layout

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Login page without Layout. I'm try to do login using ajax post method but that method not hit on the mvc Controller method.

When Im try to login alert box in success section is popup with blank. If this method hit that alert should have some record.

please help me to fix this issue.

Ajax method:

```
$('#Login').on('click', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var LoginUrl = $("#LoginUrl").val();
        var user = {
            UserName: $("#UserName").val(),
            Password: $("#Password").val(),
            RememberMe: true
        };
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: LoginUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: user,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Code);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // Reset
        }
    });

});
```

Login Form:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formLogin" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Username" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="foot">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <a href="/Account/ForgotPassword" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm md-close"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i>Forgot Password</a>
                                    <button id="Login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm md-close"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i>Log me in</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

Scripts :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/behaviour/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.switch/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/boostrap.validator/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/user.manager.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$("#LoginUrl").val();`? You don't appear to have an element with that id. Debug you script to see where the errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is with `datatype` which you have not specified in ajax request :-

```
$.ajax({
    url: LoginUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: user,
    dataType :'JSON',   //i think controller action is returning 'JSON', specify dataType as 'JSON' here.
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.Code);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // Reset
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your alert is empty (and not undefined) your server is not responding with a object that has any value for in data.Code. e.g. `alert({}.Code);` shows an alert with undefined whereas `data = {Code:''};alert(data.Code);` shows an empty alert as described in your question.

Probably best to use the console to debug your code instead of alerts.